# How to load more data when scroll from bottom to top jquery \ js

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, frontend

I'm working on a live chat on a dating site. So, I have a question, how I can load more data (ajax) when scrolling reaches the top of the chat(div) on a mobile device.
I need only **jquery \ vanilla** js logic.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML CODE**

```
 <div class="chat-list" id="messages" #scrollMe [scrollTop]="scrolltop" (scroll)="onScrollChat()">
      <div *ngFor="let message of Chats;let i = index">
      </div>
 </div>
```

**JS**
Here we have note the scrolltop position [old_height] before loading data.Once the data is loaded on scroll we have to get new scrolltop position[new_height]. scrollTop will be ele.scrollTop =
new_height - old_height

*note: don't put style scroll-behaviour:smooth

```
onScrollChat() {
    if (this.selectedTab != 0) {
      let ele = document.getElementById('messages');
      let old_height = ele.scrollHeight; // getting height before loading more messages

      if (ele.scrollTop == 0) {
      //call chat api to load more messages
            this.tempMsgs = data;//loaded messages
            this.Chats = this.tempMsgs.concat(this.Chats)
            this.changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
            let new_height = ele.scrollHeight
            ele.scrollTop = new_height - old_height;
      }
    }
  }
```